# dynamically English To Marathi Conversion in php

Tags: php, translation

Can somebody tell me **how to convert some English data into Marathi language dynamically in php?**
What I want is suppose some user enters any string in text box then it should get automatically converted into Marathi in other text box.
thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google Translate service.

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

This is the best you could possibly hope to do on your own. Translation is a serious science that is only just beginning, in nominal terms.

Answer (score 0):

You will need natural language processing for this. You can otherwise use third party translating services or widgets Note: I don't think it's a good idea to name any such service, so please  'search' yourself.